# How to instruct Squid to log user's activity?

Tags: logging, squid, clearos

This is the first time I got my hand on Squid. I can see that there are lots of configuration that can be modified, but all these options are so overwhelming that I am not sure where to go and set what.

My current system is ClearOS Enterprise 5.2 and it already has Squid 2.6 installed.

My current objective is to know how to configure Squid to log all users' online activity for 90 days. Which user visit which website, etc. This is for the law. What are some of the things I can do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and easiest way to create log with Squid is to install the squid log analyzer plugin.

- On CentOS it should be something like yum install sarg #look in DAG repos
- On ClearOS, [this should work](http://ccforums.clearfoundation.com/showflat.php?Cat=0&Board=webserver&Number=105623&Searchpage=1&Main=105623&Words=%20fozzyg&topic=&Search=true)  (not sure, never try using ClearOS as proxying server!)

hope this will help you

ps : Why did you choose ClearOS for your proxy server? Just curious, is it more reliable than CentOS? Have you some feed back about ClearOS?

Comment: I just wanna try something new. :-)

Comment: Ok, only used ClearOS as a fileshare server, was pretty stable and really reliable.